# CMake throws Error: could not load cache

Tags: cmake

I am trying to build [Dlib 19.0](http://dlib.net/release_notes.html) examples. I did

```
cd examples
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
cmake --build
```

to get exe now,
`cmake --build`  from the examples directory.

CMake throws: `Error: could not load cache`

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes a description of your problem and the steps you did leading to the error. Don't link to screenshots.

Comment: Are you sure CMake generated the build files successfully, i.e. `cmake ..` executed without errors?

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)).  By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.  If you would like to disassociate this post from your account, see [What is the proper route for a disassociation request?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/323395)

Comment: Did you finally solve this issue? I tried to compile dlib 19.17 and met the exact same issue.

Answer (score 51):

I guess you didn't configure your project.

1. You first need to run `cmake .` **at the project root** to generate build files. You can also run it from an empty directory to separate source and build files.
2. Then you can use `cmake --build ./` in the **build dir**.

Or, if you prefer code-only:

```
cd [root-directory-of-your-project]
cmake .
cmake --build ./
```

Comment: He executed `cmake ..`, so this could not be the answer - which would be better a comment anyway…

Comment: I had a similar problem (didn't run `cmake ..` but run `cmake --build` resulting in same error message `Error: could not load cache`. After running `cmake .`, a subsequent invocation of `cmake --build . --target all` worked flawlessly. Not running `cmake .` prior to `cmake --build` (or running `cmake ..`) results in the cmake cache not being present in the folder where `cmake --build .` is invoked - this causes the error message.

Comment: @usr1234567 obviously other people found the answer helpful, because it got many many upvotes.  Like koushik, I just needed to run `cmake .` before `cmake --build <dir-name>`.  Upvote from me!

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

1. Make sure you have enough space / correct permissions etc for the generated files to be created
2. Remove all generated files e.g. `CmakeCache.txt` and re-run `cmake ..`; check the output carefully for potential issues during this step, missing libraries etc.

Comment: Thank you, I deleted just the `CMakeCache.txt` in the project's root directory and I works now.

Answer (score 1):

cmake --build . is needed when building from your build directory

Answer (score 0):

Those who encountered this issue while using Eclipse for ESP-IDF, the solution is go to: `Window > Preferences > C/C++ > Build > Environment`, and set `IDF_CCACHE_ENABLE` to 0.